# Write Azure stream analytics output to Azure Tables

Tags: .net, azure, windows-10-iot-core, azure-stream-analytics

I want to write stream analytics output to Azure Tabale. I wrote below query for it:

```
Select * into azuretable from datasource;
```

But I cannot see data in table. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Problem was in the values of partition key and row keys values. These values should be exists in your data model, in my case should be part of input of stream analytics. For example, if we put Row Key = Time and Partition Key = RecordId then Time and RecordId should be valid properties present in input data model.

Comment: Yes, it should exist. If you would like to skip events that don't have those properties, then you can set output error policy to be true. Events which are bad will be skipped.

Comment: Just found an article this stuff clearly !! https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/cloud-data/an-introduction-to-windows-azure-table-storage/